# Only displaying the list of tables while at least a table exists

Tags: table-of-contents

How can i let Tex only display the list of tables if there exists at least one table and not if there's none?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To clarify, what you want is to be able to always specify `\listoftables`, but have a page with that heading produced only if a table exists. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, that is so.

Answer (score 8):

You can save the meaning of `\listoftables`, make the macro a no-op, but then add at the beginning of the first `table` the instruction to write in the log file that `\listoftables` has to receive its original meaning.

With `\AddToHookNext`, this is executed just once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@listoftables\listoftables
\let\listoftables\relax
\AddToHookNext{env/table/begin}{%
  \write\@auxout{\global\let\string\listoftables\string\orig@listoftables}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{Test}

\begin{table}[htp]
There is a table
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
There is a table
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `.aux` file contains

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Test}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\global \let \listoftables\orig@listoftables
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Test}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Test}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Note that `\global` is necessary, because the `.aux` file is read in a group.

If I comment out the two table environments, the output is

[image]

and no list of tables is produced.

Comment: Your example works out a strange way. If i test it in "TeXstudio", sometimes the list of tables is seen, sometimes is not whenever tables are present and if i delete the tables then after first run, the list is present, after second run, it's not.

If i test your example with "bookdown" then the list of tables won't appear no matter the tables are present or not. Without your example, the empty list of tables is present if no tables are present.

Comment: @user7351278 I don’t know what `bookdown` is, sorry. Are you sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: *bookdown* is a framework for creating different output out of R markdown files.

The distribution is up-to-date.

Comment: @user7351278 Still unclear, sorry. Possibly the conversion engine doesn’t handle the code right.

Comment: How do you check whether your code works?

Comment: @user7351278 I test the code I propose.

Comment: This is what i asked. How do you test? _bookdown_ was foreign to you, so what did you use instead?

Comment: @user7351278 LaTeX, of course.

Comment: As much as i get it, LaTeX is a format. What program did you use for running your LaTeX code and how did you use that program?

Comment: @user7351278 Either a front-end such as TeXShop, or Aquamacs (Emacs) or directly `pdflatex` from the terminal. And I never consider things such as Markdown converters. Markdown (or related systems) is handy for simple texts, but definitely not for complex ones like those I tend to write.

Comment: "TeXShop" is for an operating system that i don't use. "emacs" is pretty cumbersome to use as its keyboard shortcuts differ from traditional ones a lot if not entirely and has no user-friendly user-interface as RStudio Server has. i use RStudio Server as it makes it possible to include all dynamic R stuff. i don't know whether there's FOSS for writing such stuff into TEX-files. Here, RMarkdown comes handy as it connects everything and many subprocesses are automated with *bookdown* that organizes the whole conversion path from RMarkdown to HTML or LaTeX automatically.